# Use of Count function produces error in ElasticSearch

Tags: sql, rest, elasticsearch, kibana

Using Elasticsearch 7.*, the use of SQL Count function produces error.
Please guide what could be wrong here.

```
#Working:
GET _sql?format=txt
{
 "query": "select Id, Timestamp as StartTime, TransactionName as Service from \"com-prod-audit\" where TransactionName IN('Send') order by Timestamp desc LIMIT 10"
}

#####Updated:
GET _sql?format=txt
{
 "query": "select Id, Timestamp as StartTime, TransactionName as Service, COUNT(TransactionName) as count from \"com-prod-audit\" where TransactionName IN('Send') group by Id LIMIT 10"
}

#Error:
"type" : "verification_exception",
"reason" : "Found 1 problem\nline 1:24: Cannot use non-grouped columns [Timestamp, TransactionName], expected [Id]"
  },
  "status" : 400
```

Comment: If you are aggregating (count) then you need to add a group by clause. I think the error message itself is misleading.

Comment: The error seems pretty straight forward, you have an aggregate function but are not grouping, so what are you counting? Try `count(*) over()`

Comment: Thanks, updated my quesion. Using group by clause but still an issue.

Comment: I think you need to read up on aggregations and grouping - when you group you need to aggregate all non-grouped columns; grouping by `Id` is probably not right, Id is probably unique so you have rows in groups of 1